# English version of a Marathi expression that describes someone taking credit for someone else's work ('Aaiji chya Jivavar Baiji Udar')

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation

There is a Marathi saying,

> Aaiji chya Jivavar Baiji Udar

which means, roughly,

> At the expense of a mother-in-law's efforts, the daughter-in-law can show off her generosity.

It comes from the image of a helpless mother-in-law toiling away in the kitchen, sweeping the house, raising the kids, etc. Meanwhile, her lazy daughter-in-law is the one receiving the credit from guests for cooking such wonderful food, for keeping the house so clean, and for having such well-behaved children...

In other words, the daughter-in-law is playing the consummate host while her mother-in-law is working, unappreciated, in the background.

But it has a much wider scope:

Another example is an inefficient government taking credit for NGO/charity work, or suited employees showing off their work when it's the blue-collar behind the success.

**Is there an equivalent expression or idiom in English that describes a well-regarded person taking all the credit for someone else's unappreciated work behind the scene?**

Comment: I doubt it, because the stereotyped image of the mother-in-law is quite different, at least in British culture.

Comment: Not an exact fit but the idiom _steal someone's thunder_ is related. And, you've already used a common phrase in your question: _take credit for someone else_ (alt. _take the credit_, _take all the credit_).